# Computing $c$ that minimizes $\left(\sum_i h_i c_i\right)^2/\sum_i h_i^2 c_i$

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I need to solve the following problem. Given a set a vector of positive numbers $h_i$, find $c_i$ which solves the following optimization problem :

minimize
$$k$$

subject to

$$\begin{equation}
k\sum_i h_i^2 c_i \ge \left(\sum_i h_i c_i\right)^2,\\
c_i\ge 0 \forall i,\\
\sum_i c_i = 1\\
\end{equation}
$$

Soution using default `Minimize` is below, but it is slow and not robust. Is there a specialized solver in Mathematica that would work on this problem? I was aiming to use it for vectors of up to 1000 entries.

```
minimize[hvec_] := (
   Clear[c, k];
   d = Length[hvec];
   cvec = Array[c, d];
   poscons = Thread[cvec >= 0];
   cons = 
    poscons~Join~{Tr[cvec] == 1, 
      k Tr[hvec*hvec*cvec] >= Tr[hvec*cvec]^2};
   Minimize[{k, And @@ cons}, cvec~Join~{k}] // First
   );
h = {1., 2, 3, 4};
minimize[h]
(* Gives 0.64, but slow *)

minimize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]]
(* fails half the time *)
```

motivation for this question [on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640077/largest-k-such-that-k-operatornametr-h2-c-le-operatornametr-h-c2)

Comment: `minimize[Rationalize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3], 0]]` seems to work every time and is much faster than not using `Rationalize`.

Comment: It seems to do some algebraic magic....but increasing the size even a bit doesn't scale -- `minimize[Rationalize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5], 0]]`

Comment: Bummer.  What lengths of `hvec` are of interest?

Comment: `Length[hvec]=1000`

Comment: I don't have a proof but circumstantial evidence suggests that the minimum is `4 Min[h] Max[h]/(Min[h] + Max[h])^2` with `cvec[1]` (associated with `Min[h]`) is `Max[h]/(Min[h]+Max[h])`, `cvec[d]` (associated with `Max[h]` with `d` being the length of `h`) is `Min[h]/(Min[h]+Max[h])`, and the rest of the `cvec` values being zero.  I'll write-up that circumstantial evidence tomorrow.  If that turns out to be true, lengths of 1,000,000 will be a piece of cake.

Comment: indeed this seems to be true, the user on math.SE came up with a proof for this -- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4641276/998

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a vector of length $n$ (with elements sorted from low to high) named $h$.  I propose that the solution for the minimum value of $k$ is

$$4 h_1 h_n/(h_1+h_n)^2$$

with $c_1=h_n/(h_1+h_n)$, $c_n=h_1/(h_1+h_n)$, and $c_2,\ldots,c_{n-1}$ equal to zero.

Evidence (and not a proof) can be found using the answers of @BobHanlon and/or @JoshuaSchrier:

```
n = 5;
h = Sort[#] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, n}];
min[#] & /@ h

(*
{{c -> {0.139021, 0.963945, -8.51106*10^-9, -8.76525*10^-9, 7.09165*10^-10, 0.0360547}},
 {c -> {0.0945599, 0.975773, 9.98028*10^-9, 1.37117*10^-8, 1.84151*10^-8, 0.0242273}},
 {c -> {0.212049, 0.943832, 1.30107*10^-8, 1.49118*10^-8, 1.33727*10^-9, 0.0561675}}, 
 {c -> {0.695018, 0.776126, 1.37244*10^-8, 9.65637*10^-9, 1.08559*10^-9, 0.223874}}, 
 {c -> {0.672933, 0.785948, 1.70904*10^-8, 1.84161*10^-8, 1.84028*10^-8, 0.214051}}, 
 {c -> {0.575194, 0.825886, -1.85809*10^-8, -2.14393*10^-8, -1.46065*10^-8, 0.174114}},
 {c -> {0.341711, 0.905675, -3.1561*10^-8, -3.43697*10^-8, -3.43199*10^-8, 0.0943248}},
 {c -> {0.324236, 0.911024, 1.26525*10^-8, 1.20554*10^-8, -3.47093*10^-9, 0.0889763}},
 {c -> {0.4327, 0.876596, 1.96883*10^-8, 1.1127*10^-8, -1.4315*10^-9, 0.123404}},
 {c -> {0.723175, 0.763072, -1.32802*10^-8, -1.3256*10^-8, -1.28389*10^-8, 0.236928}}}
*)
```

All of the middle values of $c$ are essentially zero.

To find the general formula consider $n=2$:

```
result = Minimize[{(c1 h1 + (1 - c1) h2)^2/(h1^2 c1 + h2^2 (1 - c1)), 
  {0 <= c1 <= 1, 0 < h1 < h2}}, c1]
```

[image: Solution for minimum k when n=2]

Now simplify the results:

```
kmin = PiecewiseExpand[result[[1]], Assumptions -> h2 > 0 && 0 < h1 < h2]
(* (4 h1 h2)/(h1 + h2)^2 *)

c1optimal = PiecewiseExpand[c1 /. result[[2]], Assumptions -> 0 < h1 < h2]
(* h2/(h1 + h2) *)

c2optimal = 1 - c1opt // Together
(* h1/(h1 + h2) *)
```

Can these formulas match the results of the functions of the other two answers?  Yes.

```
{4 #[[1]] #[[n]]/(#[[1]] + #[[n]])^2, #[[n]]/(#[[1]] + #[[n]]), #[[1]]/(#[[1]] + #[[n]])} & /@ h

(* {{0.139023, 0.963944, 0.0360557}, 
    {0.0945581, 0.975774, .0242264},
    {0.212047, 0.943834, 0.0561665},
    {0.695017, 0.776126, 0.223874}, 
    {0.672932, 0.785949, 0.214051},
    {0.575195, 0.825885, 0.174115}, 
    {0.341713, 0.905675, 0.0943255}, 
    {0.324234, 0.911025, 0.0889751}, 
    {0.432699, 0.876597, 0.123403}, 
    {0.723176, 0.76307,  0.23693}}
*)
```

Again, this is not a proof but at minimum this procedure will duplicate all combinations I've tried so far.

**Addition:** The formula works for positive real numbers outside of 0 and 1:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
h = RandomVariate[ChiSquareDistribution[4], 5] // Sort
(* {1.40875, 1.85093, 3.99801, 4.17544, 6.9753} *)

min[h]
(* {c -> {0.559176, 0.831973, -7.5885*10^-9, -6.03915*10^-9, -5.86735*10^-9, 0.168027}} *)

{hmin, hmax} = MinMax[h];
{4 hmin hmax/(hmin + hmax)^2, hmax/(hmin + hmax), hmin/(hmin + hmax)} // N
(* {0.559176, 0.831973, 0.168027} *)
```

Comment: This is starting to remind me of some of the "pre-calculus optimizations" discussed in Paul Nahin's [When Least is Best](https://amzn.to/3YHdGly), in particular using the [inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) to reason for discarding the middle terms

Comment: A caveat might be that our examples so far have considered the entries in h to be 0<h<1, but I'm not sure that is guaranteed in @YaroslavBulatov's original question

Comment: Ah, solving symbolically for d=2 was a nice trick to get the formula. Someone with quantum information background gave proof of this formula this morning [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640077/largest-k-such-that-k-operatornametr-h2-c-le-operatornametr-h-c2/4641276#4641276)

Comment: Yes, that proof should be the accepted answer here.

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier Good point.  I've added an example with values greater than 1.

Answer (score 3):

*Updated 17 Feb 2023, with a second (and better) attempt...*

**Attempt 1:**

I get a reasonable speedup (and reliable result) with the following:

```mathematica
min[h_] := With[
  {probabilitySimplex = Simplex@IdentityMatrix@Length[h]},
  Minimize[(h.c)^2/((h*h).c), c \[Element] probabilitySimplex]]

h = {1., 2, 3, 4}; (*example from above*)
minimize[h];//AbsoluteTiming (*0.50 s, using function from original post*)
min[h];//AbsoluteTiming (*0.16 s using new function*)
```

However, the lack of convergence remains with random parameters. If we `Histogram` the running time (with `Minimize` failing to converge at long times) we see the following:

```mathematica
Histogram@ParallelTable[
 First@AbsoluteTiming@min@RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3],
 {10^3}]
```

[image: histogram of the result of above code]

Also, it doesn't seem like this solves the running time scaling to reach the desired goal of N=1000 (y axis is in units of seconds, running on an early 2020 Intel MacBook Pro with a million browser tabs open, but...)

```mathematica
ListPlot@ParallelTable[
  First@AbsoluteTiming@min@N@Range[i],
  {i, 1, 50}]
```

[image: plot of the scaling of problem time with number of items calculated by the previous code]

**Attempt 2**

Based on a suggestion from @YaroslavBulatov's comment, this can be made much faster as a `ConvexOptimization`. The trick is to create an expanded vector so that the `k` value becomes the first entry in the list (and can be multiplied by zero):

```mathematica
min[h_?VectorQ] :=
 With[
  {hSq = Prepend[0]@(h*h),
   hSi = Prepend[0]@h,
   totalConstraint = Prepend[0]@ConstantArray[1, Length[h]],
   kConstraint = Prepend[1]@ConstantArray[0, Length[h]]},
  ConvexOptimization[ 
   kConstraint.c, (* minimize k*)
   {(kConstraint.c)*(hSq.c) >= (hSi.c)^2,
    totalConstraint.c == 1},
   c \[Element] Vectors[Length[h] + 1, PositiveReals]]]

(*demo*)
AbsoluteTiming@min@RandomReal[{0, 1}, 1000] (*0.25 seconds*)
```

This is now tractably fast for the problem in the original post.  FWIW, you may get some `Requested tolerance` warnings for large problems, but this should not be a problem in practice.  I suspect that this could be made even faster by using one of the fancier commercial solvers by setting the `Method` option, but I don't have any of these installed.

Comment: Inspired by @BobHanlon's answer: you could change `Minimize` to `MinValue` if you only care about the value of `k`...I was curious to see what the solutions looked liked.

Comment: `Simplex` is a nice UI trick. I'm wondering if some of the solvers recently added to Mathematica would work here https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/12/13/new-in-13-optimization-pdes-system-modeling/

Comment: Great idea @YaroslavBulatov .... check out the second attempt above.  It appears to be fast enough to do this.  Depending on the choice of the h values, there are occasionally convergence warnings, but these can likely be turned off.  If interested in the value of k along, just take the `First` entry in the list of returned optimization parameters...

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Add the constraint that `k > 0`

```
minimize[hvec_?VectorQ] := Module[
  {c, cons, cvec, d, k, poscons},
  d = Length[hvec];
  cvec = Array[c, d];
  poscons = Thread[cvec >= 0];
  cons = poscons~
    Join~{Tr[cvec] == 1, k Tr[hvec*hvec*cvec] >= Tr[hvec*cvec]^2, k > 0};
  MinValue[{k, And @@ cons}, cvec~Join~{k}]]

h = {1., 2, 3, 4}; minimize[h]

(* 0.640001 *)
```

A failure is rare.

```
SeedRandom[1234];

Table[Check[minimize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]],
   Print[$Failed]], 900] // Short[#, 5] &
```

[image]

One failure in 900 evaluations.